# React : ENOENT Error while trying to pulish on git pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I've been trying to post my web app on Github pages but while building the app using the npm run deploy command this error keeps on popping. I'm new to react and can't seem to find what the problem is.the git path is added in env variables. I'm on windows. [this is the snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJLts.png).

[the deploy script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Vd9.png)

Comment: Could you please post as text the commands and error messages? It helps the community to solve your issue. Thank you!

Comment: did you add a "homepage:" property to your _package.json_?

Comment: yes, I did add a homepage properly.

Answer (score -1):

Try using npm run build and follow the instructions, after that a new folder will be created inside the root folder of your project, and that folder is a compression of your project, and the one you need to deploy on Github.

Comment: that didnt help